# How to set the initial start screen for a tab with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-jetpack-compose

Right now, the start screen is the "**Camera Screen**" (at index 0)

[image]

I want to set the start screen to the "**Chat Screen**" (i.e index 1 not 0)

That is: When the user opens the app, the "**Chat Screen**" is the active screen and NOT the **"Camera Screen"**  -- Just like how it is on whatsApp

```
private val tabs = listOf(
TabItem.Camera,
TabItem.Chat,
TabItem.Status,
TabItem.Call
)

@Composable
fun TabLayout(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
tabs: List<TabItem>,
selectedIndex: Int = 1,
onPageSelected: ((tabItem: TabItem) -> Unit)
) {

TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
    divider = { }
) {

    tabs.forEachIndexed{index, tabItem ->

        Tab(
            selected = index == selectedIndex,
            modifier = modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
            onClick = {
            onPageSelected(tabItem)
        },

            text =
            {
                if (tabItem == TabItem.Camera) {
                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_camera), stringResource(id = R.string.icon)).toString()
                }

                else {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = tabItem.title).uppercase(Locale.ROOT),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
                    )
                }

            },
        )
    }
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

 //tab layout
TabLayout(tabs = tabs, selectedIndex = pagerState.currentPage ,
    onPageSelected = { tabItem->
        coroutineScope.launch {
            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(tabItem.index)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is the selected tab (the line under the tabs) changed if you go to another tabs?

Comment: Yes, it changes

Comment: You pass pager current page. Did you check if it is 1?

Comment: Its starting from 0 @Marat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this was pretty easy.

All I had to do was override the default initial state of *pagerState*

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 1)
```

Comment: Since you are passing in pagerState.currentPage to your tabLayout, the currentPage value will control which tab you see initially

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `selectedIndex` variable that you're passing into TabRow as 1.

Comment: Hi. I did that. The Camera Screen is still the first, selected screen instead of the Chats Tab.

Check edited question

Comment: Can you post how you are calling the `TabLayout` composable?

Comment: I have updated the question to include that.

Comment: Hi @Jacob, I still havn't found a fix for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use state for the selected tab:

```
@Composable
fun TabLayout(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
tabs: List<TabItem>,
selectedIndex: Int = 1,
onPageSelected: ((tabItem: TabItem) -> Unit)
) {
 var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(selectedIndex) }

TabRow(
  selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
  divider = { }
 ) {

tabs.forEachIndexed{index, tabItem ->

    Tab(
        selected = index == tabIndex,
        modifier = modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
        onClick = {
          tabIndex = index
          onPageSelected(tabItem)
        },
```

Comment: Sadly, didn't work. With this, the line under the tabs doesn't move. It just stays in the first 'camera screen'

Comment: Hi @Marat, I still havn't found a fix for this.. :(

Answer (score 0):

replace Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
to Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[tabIndex])

tabIndex value is equals to 1

see https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.material3/material3/1.0.0-alpha08-source/androidx/compose/material3/TabRow.kt.html